# How to use a created JMenuBar in each of the java swing form?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jmenubar

I have created a `JMenuBar` and I want to use that `JMenuBar` in every form of my swing application. Writing `JMenuBar` in every form is not an efficient programming. 
So, I want to use the same `JMenuBar` in every form. But I have no clue how to do it. 
Can anyone show me some sample, so I can use it in my project.

Comment: `Can anyone show me some sample, so I can use it in my project. ` yes we can help you, but **1)** we have no idea how your project looks like. **2)** Can you show us what have you tried and where you're stuck? Please consider reading [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) section and [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be making the JMenuBar Object public and static to allow access from every other class in the program without creating extra instances.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was actually thought about that. Let me see .